# subsciption failed when using polygon io

Tags: websocket, polygon

I have an issue when attempting to connect Polygon's websockets though I already paid subscription today(Saturday).[image][image] Succeeded to proceed connection and authentication steps but failed to process subscription stemp. Can someone help me about this problem?

installed everything

Answer (score 0):

Ian from Polygon here! I would be happy to help further debug this issue! Would you mind reaching out to support@polygon.io or going through the intercom support chat on our [site](https://polygon.io/)? This way we can look up your account information and make sure you are on the correct subscription.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).